# Installing twitcurl on OS X

Tags: c++, macos, twitter, makefile, clang

I am attempting to install twitcurl on OS X and have met with some problems.

At first, running `make` would return the clang error: `ld: unknown option: -soname`. I looked through the responses from other users with similar problems on OS X and found the following advice:

In the makefile, change:

```
LDFLAGS += -Wl,-rpath-link=$(STAGING_DIR)/usr/lib
```

to:

```
LDFLAGS += -rpath=$(STAGING_DIR)/usr/lib
```

change:

```
$(CC) -shared -Wl,-soname,lib$(LIBNAME).so.1 $(LDFLAGS) -o lib$(LIBNAME).so.1.0 .o -L$(LIBRARY_DIR) -lcurl
```

to:

```
$(CC) -dynamiclib -shared -Wl,-install_name,lib$(LIBNAME).dylib.1 $(LDFLAGS) -o lib$(LIBNAME).dylib .o -L$(LIBRARY_DIR) -lcurl
```

I tried this, but the only result was another clang error: `clang: error: unknown argument: '-rpath=/usr/lib'`

Any advice towards installing twitcurl on an OS X system will be greatly appreciated.

----UPDATE----

I just wanted to put in one place all the steps I took to make this work, in case any OS X users with similar problems come across this in the future. My thanks to Andy Piper for the crucial pieces.

open the makefile and replace:

`LDFLAGS += -Wl,-rpath-link=$(STAGING_DIR)/usr/lib`

with:

`LDFLAGS += -rpath $(STAGING_DIR)/usr/lib`

and:

`$(CC) -shared -Wl,-soname,lib$(LIBNAME).so.1 $(LDFLAGS) -o lib$(LIBNAME).so.1.0 .o -L$(LIBRARY_DIR) -lcurl`

with:

`$(CC) -dynamiclib -shared -Wl,-install_name,lib$(LIBNAME).dylib.1 $(LDFLAGS) -o lib$(LIBNAME).dylib *.o -L$(LIBRARY_DIR) -lcurl`
(note that this is different by two characters from the advice another OS X user gave above)

after running make, copy `libtwitcurl.dylib` into `/usr/lib/`

Downloading the twitterClient (which is also the only code example I could find) will be the same, but for compiling it or your own programs you will need to link `-lcurl` as well. (`g++ appname.cpp -ltwitcurl -lcurl`)

Finally, once you compile a program, the path name will likely be incorrect in the executable which is created. Use install_name_tool to correct it. For me this looks like:

`install_name_tool -change libtwitcurl.dylib.1 /usr/lib/libtwitcurl.dylib nameofexecutable`

but if that doesn't work for you, use otool to find the actual path:

`otool -L nameofexecutable`

and then the first argument after -change should be the erroneous path for libtwitcurl. You can use otool again after running install_name_tool to be sure the change was successful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can get the shared / dynamic library to compile but needed to make a couple of adjustments to your Makefile:

```
LDFLAGS += -rpath $(STAGING_DIR)/usr/lib
```

and

```
$(CC) -dynamiclib -shared -Wl,-install_name,lib$(LIBNAME).dylib.1 $(LDFLAGS) -o lib$(LIBNAME).dylib *.o -L$(LIBRARY_DIR) -lcurl
```

I've now also built the associated twitterClient utility. To do so, I had to symbolically link libtwitcurl.dylib as libtwitcurl.dylib.1 and also change the consumer key and secret in the code to match a valid one from apps.twitter.com on my account. Works fine.

I assume you want to use the twitcurl library from code? Twitter maintains a Ruby-based utility, [twurl](http://github.com/twitter/twurl), which has a similar function and may also be useful.

Comment: These are the same changes I made - when I run `sudo make` with these changes I get `clang: error: unknown argument: '-rpath=/usr/lib'
make: *** [target] Error 1` - I will work in a different language if I am unable to get this to work - but i would prefer to use C++ if I can.

Comment: not quite the same. Note: there's no "=" after rpath in mine, and in the second command, theres a "*.o" instead of ".o"

Comment: also - you shouldn't (!) need to use `sudo` to execute this build.

Comment: When I try without sudo I get a series of  `error: unable to open output file` errors. I apologize for missing the changes! The make commands worked. I now am getting linker errors however when I try to compile an example program. I moved libtwitcurl.dylib to `/usr/lib/` as the instructions suggested, and tried to compile with `g++ program.cpp -ltwitcurl` - how do i find out where clang is looking for the library?

Comment: I linked `-lcurl` as well, and now the only error I'm getting is: `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable`

Comment: nevermind. I was making an error. thank you for your help! I cant award the bounty yet, but I will.